# TFS Duplicate work item link

Tags: c#, tfs

I have a program which makes the links between two workitems automatically.

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll

Additional information: TF237099: Duplicate work item link.

```
WorkItemLinkType linkType = wis.WorkItemLinkTypes[CoreLinkTypeReferenceNames.Related];
tfsProblem.workitem1.Links.Add(new WorkItemLink(linkType.ForwardEnd, tfsEvent.workitem2.Id));
tfsProblem.workitem1.Save();
```

How to fix the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to duplicate work items in TFS 2018 through REST API and have both work items reference each other. I've been told that it should be coded in C#. I have no clue how I should go about it since I've neither worked with REST APIs, nor worked with TFS. Can anyone guide me on this? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if there is a link in workitem1 to workitem2 before adding a new one:

```
LinkCollection links = tfsProblem.workitem1.Links;
if (!links.Any(x => ((Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.RelatedLink) (x)).RelatedWorkItemId == tfsEvent.workitem2.Id)
{
   WorkItemLinkType linkType = wis.WorkItemLinkTypes[CoreLinkTypeReferenceNames.Related];
   tfsProblem.workitem1.Links.Add(new WorkItemLink(linkType.ForwardEnd, tfsEvent.workitem2.Id));
   tfsProblem.workitem1.Save();
}
```